# Erase Data from a Field without a name acess vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to erase some data (values = 0) from a field in access, but without knowing the name, I only know the position of the field in the database (13ºcolumn) . I thought it would be very simple, but after many tries I still can't manage to find a solution and I am starting to doubt if it's even possible.

So this is the code that I am using:

```
Sub Erasevalues0()
Dim strQValue As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim sql13 As String

Set db = CurrentDb

sql13 = db.TableDefs("TableName").Fields(13).Name

strQValue = "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE  sql13=0;"
db.Execute strQValue

End Sub
```

I even tried something like:

```
strQValue = "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE  Fields(13)=0;"
```

But nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you ever delete based on the ordinal of the field?

Comment: Because it was imported from excel and the name of the field can change slightly but not the position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to loop through the recordset. The following should work

```
Sub RemoveZeros()

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Table1", dbOpenDynaset)

rs.MoveFirst
With rs
 Do Until .EOF
   If .Fields(13) = 0 Then .Delete 'Delete row if column 13 = 0
   .MoveNext 'Move to next record
 Loop
End With
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a direct way to use the index of a field. A workaround:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM TableName"
columnName = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(query).Fields(13).Name

strQValue = "UPDATE TableName " & _
            "SET " & columnName & "=''"
```